# Why can't I start a bounty?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

On SO and Meta it will not let me start a bounty....

[image: first bounty screenshot]

(Chrome dies here, but only sometimes)

---

[image: second bounty screenshot]

---

[image: third bounty screenshot]

This last picture is where I get stuck. I press the "Start Bounty" button but nothing happens. I've tried entering a message for the user, even though it says "optional", but it still does not work. There are no Javascript errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you happen to know if you're getting any errors in Chrome's developer console?

Comment: Don't even know what that is. If you tell me how to check I will.

Comment: Hit F12 to open the developer tools in chrome (a big section should show up at the bottom). There's tabs at the top of the new section; click the Console one and then try and post a bounty. See if there are any new errors (in red) in the output after attempting to send the bounty. My guess is the javascript is failing

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what happened. I pressed F12 then tried to post a bounty and the bounty just worked. Not sure what the problem is but it was solved, thanks for your time.

Comment: Even though this was resolved for the original author, voting to reopen as someone else seems to have [the same problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143224/cant-start-a-bounty), but this very question is much more detailed.

Comment: had exactly the same issue at MSO, with [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141197/more-review-mayhem-copied-content) - WinXP, FF 12 and IE 8. At the same time, in the same environment (FF), I succeeed to offer a bounty at [another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129839/bypassing-the-review-queue-for-avid-editors)

Comment: Same issue on my end too. Win 7 firefox 14.0.1

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well. IE9 on Win 7.  I've checked the console and there's nothing.

Comment: I tried again a while later and it worked properly.

Comment: So if you can't open a bounty, how did you open this one?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Mine actually just started working randomly. But I didn't start this bounty, this question was closed a few days ago. Someone else re-opened it and put a bounty on it.

Comment: I was having the same problem in Chrome & Firefox (OS X). I tried several times with no luck. I checked with VisualEvent, and jQuery was subscribed to the submit event on the form, but no code was shown for the event. About 10 minutes later I tried again, and it worked.

Comment: I am also getting this as an issue wtf.

Comment: i too am getting this error. latest version of chrome. win7. javascript is enabled, no extensions are being used

Comment: I am also not able to start a bounty

Comment: This happens randomly in FF and Chrome. Meta won't let me offer a bounty. Chrome stops on "Next" in the first popup (no JS errors), Firefox dies at Start Bounty (no js errors). It just silently fails.

Comment: For the record it took 4 tries and two browsers to set this bounty, after another several failures at applying another bounty.

Comment: It happened in both IE8 and Chrome, and it stopped on "Start Bounty"b both times.

Comment: Creating a bounty with Chrome 21.0.1180.81 on Ubuntu did not work for the same reason.  Was able to do so with Firefox though.

Comment: @bart - [It's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty#comment407059_143271) on you now...

Comment: @Lix I got closer and closer to 10k, which means your girlfriend would have to bake me a cake. Didn't want to do that to her just yet... (or is that not how that works?)

Comment: @bar - haha... **no**.  It doesn't work like that!  You'll get a cupcake *if* you ask very nicely ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We (read: Emmett) pushed a fix for this a few days ago, so it should be all good now.

We were missing a variable declaration that usually wasn't a problem by sheer coincidence.

If this is still broken for you and you're running the SEModifications userscript, update it to the latest version.

Comment: Any info as to what the problem was? (For no other reason than that I'm a nosy bastard)

Comment: @Bart Something something javascript something. Hold on, lemme find the chat log. :)

Comment: Haha, I will quote you on that should the question ever come up.

Comment: Nope - still happening

Comment: ([for future reference purposes](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1125750#1125750))

Answer (score 9):

Ok so I was having this issue in chrome...I tried it in IE and firefox and nothing was working. The way I got it to work was I click `Start Bounty` and go through the process. When I got to the third screen where everyone is having an issue with the button, I scrolled down and clicked on `Start Bounty` again (Leaving the first start bounty window open). You now have `two` bounty windows open. In the new window go through the process and then try and submit the bounty. I don't know which `submit` button I clicked on but one of them worked successfully

Comment: Mine already works, so if anyone else is having trouble with the problem, comment please and let us know if this is working.

Comment: Well as of 5 minutes ago mine wasn't working

Comment: I know, I just feel like there is an issue that must have a definitive answer that will explain why it keeps happening. Mine started randomly working, and the only thing that I noticed doing was pressing the F12 key. I'd like to accept an answer that has an exact answer that will help everyone, not just something that worked once.

Comment: I was in the F12 area and had no idea what I was looking for. I did notice that when highlighting the form tag, the submit button was not part of the highlight. It was clearly in between the form tag however

Comment: Same problem using FF on Win 7 - this solution worked for me.

Comment: Same problem in Chrome 21.0.1180.89 on Ubuntu 11.10; this workaround helped. "I'd like to accept an answer that has an exact answer that will help everyone, not just something that worked once." -- I'd like the bug fixed. This is a workaround.

Comment: Not sure if you're directing that comment towards me or the devs. I am well aware that this is a workaround, but hey it's helping people start some bounties :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just checked and the "Start Bounty" is ordinary submit button that is posting a form to the server with all the required information.

This means that if clicking it does not work some JavaScript code is blocking the click event.

Since there is no direct click event, most likely some jQuery code is attached at some point and on some browsers under specific conditions that still need to be reproduced, block the click event of the button.

<strike>As a workaround for those who can't start a bounty due to this problem, I suggest to disable JavaScript in their browser then the button will work just fine, being ordinary HTML submit button.</strike>
On second thought, disabling JavaScript won't work either since the bounty window itself is loaded by jQuery.

Comment: Oh the irony of placing a bounty on a question titled - `"Why can't I start a bounty?"`... classic :)