# Can't start a bounty

Tags: bug, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I start a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty)

I want to offer a bounty on [my question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849918/graphical-multiple-file-pair-comparison-on-mac-os-10-7).

However, I can't seem to do so. I encounter a problem similar to the one described in this question: [Why can't I start a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty)

I follow the same procedure as in the pictures shown there.

My OS is MacOS 10.7 and my browser is Opera 12.01 (same for Safari 6.0).

Please, help me to find the reason and start the bounty.

Comment: here is the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849918/graphical-multiple-file-pair-comparison-on-mac-os-10-7

Comment: isn't is suppose to tell me what is wrong if my question doesn't satisfy the requirements?

Comment: I can see the "start a bounty" link.

Comment: And what does it mean? I can see it too.

Comment: Assuming this is a browser thing for a moment, could you try clearing your cache and try again?

Comment: There is a close vote on the question. Not sure if it prevents you from starting a bounty.

Comment: Bart, i did it. Doesn't help.

Comment: nhahtdh, "close vote" means vote to close the question? I can't see it...

Comment: @nhahtdh: It does not.

Comment: I checked Safari browser too - it doesn't work either.

Comment: So it's *exactly* the same as the other question? You go through all the screens, but the "Start Bounty" button on the last one does nothing?

Comment: Yes. The last window just stays where it was.

Comment: So have you looked for errors in FireBug or the Chrome developer console or some other JavaScript console?

Comment: I understood Chorme developer console is for Chrome users, not Opera. I will try to install FireBug, if you are advicing me this.

Comment: If all is exactly the same, shouldn't we vote to re-open the other much more detailed question, and close this one?

Comment: @kim123 -- sorry, I didn't notice which browser you're using. For Opera, use [dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/).

Comment: Cant reproduce. Successfully added a bounty on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487731/how-do-you-upload-a-video-to-youtube-using-json-c-format

Comment: No repro in IE 6

Comment: I think it must've been a bug, someone else reported it [here][1] too.


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143274/start-a-bounty-failure-for-a-own-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done a thing, but now, 6 hours later it works. I have started it finally.
Mean while 3 hours ago it didn't work.