# Start a bounty failure for a own question

Tags: bug, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I start a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty)

I have raised a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841432/looking-for-sql-profiler-for-sybase-since-we-are-using-orm-that-hides-the-sql-sc) in stackoverflow on 7th August 2012 but there is not much attention for that question. So I decided to start a bounty for that question today but I am not able to do that.
I have the link for `start bounty` which opens the dialog. After choosing a reason for the bounty, it ends in a custom reason creation dialog. Clicking the button `start bounty` in that dialog is not working.

Now I am able to start bounty. Hope there is an issue for short period of time.

Comment: So it's resolved now? Did you do anything in particular which seemed to solve it?

Comment: I didnt do anything but its resolved by itself. I am curious to know the root cause for this happening at that time.

Comment: Quite sure JavaScript problem, hope a dev will take a look and explain it soon.