# Problem creating Bounty

Tags: bug, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I start a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty)

I have been trying for the past 24 hours to create a bounty but the "Start Bounty" button is not responding. Any information on why please?

Comment: On what question?

Comment: Similar situation as this I assume: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty

Comment: It may be similar but apparently there is no ANSWER there so what do I do?