# Cannot add bounties on meta.SO, SO and well... every other SE site

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I start a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty)

I am unable to get past the next button when adding a bounty to a question. What could be the problem? (I have no bounties open anywhere)

Google Chrome Mac Version 21.0.1180.89

Comment: @Chichiray I cannot get to the third screen, I am on the first screen. Clicking start bounty again only bring up more popups