# Can not start bounty

Tags: support, bug, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I start a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty)

I want to start a bounty on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290440/mvc-3-creates-a-new-database-instead-of-using-the-one-specified#) however nothing happens when i click on start in the last dialog (add additional comments)

When I click on start nothing happens, the dialog does not close, no messages, nothing, it's like I have not clicked the start button.

I have tried with and without comments.

Comment: @jmort253 sorry about that, hope i added enough information

Comment: Not sure if this should be closed, even though it might be a duplicate, considering the other one never got officially fixed and involved a hack from several users to get it to work.

Comment: @jmort253 It also hasn't got an accepted answer yet. If you feel it has not gotten the attention it deserves, a bounty would be the correct approach. Not a duplicate question.

Comment: sorry i'm not sure i understood the user answer i need to open two webpages with the same question and start the bounty on both?

Comment: @EH_warch No, not really. The duplicate only indicates that this problem has been reported before. It seems there were some work-arounds as suggested by other users. But they are not necessarily solutions.

Comment: @EH_warch No, it's saying you should click "start bounty" twice on the same page. (Disclaimer: no idea if it actually works.)

Comment: (I also passed this on to the devs since it keeps happening fairly regularly.)

Comment: FWIW I've started a bounty on the duplicate to get it some more attention. Let's see if it does any good. :)