# Automatically compare tag wiki edits against a Google search

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More review mayhem: copied content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141197/more-review-mayhem-copied-content)

While this is similar to "[What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted#comment404609_137784)?", this is a direct feature request.

Everyone makes mistakes, but I recently rejected another tag wiki excerpt for copying and pasting straight from Adobe's website, but within seconds a moderator approved the same edit.  There was no source, no attribution, or anything, and a quick search would have shown that it was copied.

Would it be possible to have one or more of the following enhancements added to the tag wiki approval process?

1. When a tag wiki and/or excerpt is submitted, do a quick search of Google and per-emptively reject any suggestions that are 95%-100% copied and pasted and show up in the top X number of Google search results?
2. Show a small window next to the tag wiki (or excerpt) showing search results that contain a high probability match, so the user can confirm if the text is properly sourced or not.
3. At a minimum, have the "Approve" button for tag wikis (and excerpts) be disabled until a user checks a box next to it that reads "I have confirmed the text is either original or properly sourced".  You would be surprised how much a little checkbox would go to keep people from rapid-fire pressing "Approve".  This would probably be the easiest one to do.