# What will happen to my activities if account deleted?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

What will happen to my Questions, Answers, Comments etc if I delete my account?

Comment: They will generally remain on the site, but in an anonymous form.

Comment: anonymous form???

Comment: Yep @SubinJacob. No longer will it appear as from "Subin Jacob" but from a userxxxxx with no account to link to. See for example [this particular question for an illustration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190665/a-comment-box-to-verify-suspected-plagiarism-when-reviewing)

Comment: @Bart on some places we may still see "Subin Jacob" but gray and not linked. (e.g. revisions, actions like delete or CW posts)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd such as? @ replies perhaps, but generally...

Comment: @Bart yep `@` replies too but I edited few more into my comment.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ah true.